# Is it possible to run Safari in the background on the iPhone and monitor a user's location?

Tags: iphone, html, gps, mobile-safari

Is it possible to run Safari in the background on the iPhone?

Specifically, our client would like to monitor a user's location via HTML5 GPS capabilities and measure the speed of movement.

The reason for avoiding native implementation in iOS is because the client wishes to create a cross-platform service using HTML5.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe Safari continues to execute when it's backgrounded. (This is supported by a recent thread on the [Apple discussion board](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=12449786).)

That said, it would be fairly trivial to do this in a proper iOS application, although you'd obviously need existing knowledge of Objective-C, some of the main Cocoa/UIKit classes, the Xcode environment, etc.)

Comment: Really? I understood that there is no general multitasking, just some specific services. In general apps which are backgrounded seem to get "frozen" although some events may be assigned a handler. I don't really know that much about the API though.

Comment: Thanks, @middaparka.  I understand it's trivial in an iOS app, and I should have elaborated on the motivation behind the question.  The client would like to create a cross-platform service and therefore use HTML5.  Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: @extraeon - It was one of the selling points of iOS 4. See the "Background location" bits within the Multitasking section on http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/whats-new.html :-)