# How to upload file through website, on mobile?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mobile, file-upload

Is it possible to create a file/s upload system, on a mobile friendly **website**, that uploads the file from the mobile when it gets internet connection?

To put in a scenario: User X wants to upload 3 images on the website. X is outside, opens the website on this phone and selects the images he wants to upload. When he is about to start the upload, or has just started he looses internet connection. X then locks his phone, goes somewhere where there is internet and the file uploads continues and finishes. Is there a way to achieve something similar to this?

This is similar to [Is there a browser file upload solution that can survive connection interruptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449373/is-there-a-browser-file-upload-solution-that-can-survive-connection-interruption)
but the answers are over two years old. This question also doesn't talk about mobile, but I don't know if it matters with the file upload.

Sorry for the bad english and grammar

Regards

Comment: Couple of links to get you started: [Continue uploading process in background IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788106/continue-uploading-process-in-background-ios) and [Is it possible to run Safari in the background on the iPhone and monitor a user's location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356117/is-it-possible-to-run-safari-in-the-background-on-the-iphone-and-monitor-a-user). This is just for iOS and Safari, you'll need to look into other mobile OS, as well. Possibly, you will need an app to accomplish what you want (because then you are in control of the background activity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly possible. However I don't think a browser based solution will do. This has to do with both server and client side connections.

For example. In a traditional web server environment, the server will not keep a connection open when user looses its connectivity. When the user re-gains the connectivity the server may not know the state in which the client [or browser] is in ... so the client will need to communicate that state back to the server.

On the other hand the browser will also cease its connection irrespective of the fact whether its a mobile app or not.

I think you will need to supply an intelligent client , perhaps a Java based app to remember those issue and re-supply the broken session information to the server.

And just like that the server will need to be able to handle that .. though it can be an http server.